# What's the most idiomatic way to to remove collection elements with values containing one or more of a given collection of words?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

Supposing I wanted to remove the list elements mentioning the animals in the banned-from-house collection:

```
(def list (atom [{:animal "a quick happy brown fox that rocks!"}
                 {:animal "a quick happy brown hamster that rocks!"}
                 {:animal "a quick happy brown bird that rocks!"}
                 {:animal "a quick happy brown dog and fox that rock!"}
                 {:animal "a quick happy brown fish that rocks!"}]))

(def banned-from-house (atom ["fox" "bird"]))
```

What would be the most idiomatic way to go about that?

Also, what would be a better title for this question? (I struggle in discussing clojure code)

Comment: First, get rid of those atoms :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's build this step by step.

First, let's test if a String mentions some animal name, using [`clojure.string/includes?`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.string-api.html#clojure.string/includes?).

```
(defn mentions-animal? [s animal]
  (clojure.string/includes? s animal))

(mentions-animal?
  "a quick happy brown fox that rocks!"
  "fox")
=> true
(mentions-animal?
  "a quick happy brown fox that rocks!"
  "dog")
=> false
```

Second, let's test if a string mentions *some* of a seq of animal names, using [`clojure.core/some`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some).

```
(defn mentions-any? [s animals]
  (some #(mentions-animal? s %) animals))

(mentions-any?
  "a quick happy brown fox that rocks!"
  #{"fox" "dog"})
=> true
(mentions-any?
  "a quick happy brown fox that rocks!"
  #{"cat" "dog"})
=> nil
```

Next, extend this logic to animal maps instead of strings.

```
(defn animal-mentions-any? 
  [a animals]
  (mentions-any? (:animal a) animals))
```

Finally, implement the filtering logic using [`clojure.core/remove`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/remove):

```
(defn remove-banned-animals 
  [animals-list banned-animals]
  (remove #(animal-mentions-any? % banned-animals) animals-list))

(remove-banned-animals
  [{:animal "a quick happy brown fox that rocks!"}
   {:animal "a quick happy brown hamster that rocks!"}
   {:animal "a quick happy brown bird that rocks!"}
   {:animal "a quick happy brown dog and fox that rock!"}
   {:animal "a quick happy brown fish that rocks!"}]
  ["fox" "bird"])
=> ({:animal "a quick happy brown hamster that rocks!"} {:animal "a quick happy brown fish that rocks!"})
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much. I was a bit stumped about how to do it with this brevity as I didn't know about 'includes?'. The step-wise explanation is also great.

Comment: just one note: since we want to classify data by some word inclusion, it is probably better to use regexp instead of `includes?` , (something like `#"\bfox\b"`), to avoid problems with words, including your target ones (like `"a quick happy brown dog dancing foxtrot"`)

Comment: @leetwinski I agree, but even regexps have shortcomings (pluralization etc.), in which case the solution would be to use an NLP library. It seemed to me the focus of the question was code organization, which is why I opted for a simplistic solution.